# Does an airborne chemical stimulant exist?

Tags: pharmacology

I recently read the creepypasta entitled "The Russian Sleep Experiment". In this story they lock five test subjects in a room with the intention of keeping them awake for 30 days by releasing a gaseous stimulant into the room constantly. I'll let you read the rest, it's an incredible horror story, but not very credible. Anyways I wanted to know if in real life such a gaseous stimulant exists.

During the Moscow theater hostage crisis Russian forces "pumped an aerosol anaesthetic, later stated by Russian Health Minister Yuri Shevchenko to be based on fentanyl". So it's possible for an opiate-based depressant can be made gaseous (technically aerosol).

So is there an airborne stimulant that actually exists?

Comment: Gaseous: no. Aerosol: yes.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether the stimulant is actually gaseous at standard temperature and pressure, it can be made airborne as an aerosol simply by spraying. If the room to be filled with vapour is sufficiently small then it is no problem to just spray a solution of your stimulant and pump it inside. But even gym hall sizes should be fine with adequate technique applied.